# How to include additional attributes in the SCIM responses using WSO2 charon?

Tags: wso2, scim

I'm using WSO2 5.1. The SCIM GET requests to retrieve users return responses that contain only a small number of attributes. How do I make it return additional attributes?

The documentation for the GET user request on [WSO2's SCIM API page](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/SCIM+APIs) says "The response consists of all attributes that were sent." This doesn't make sense - how do you send attributes with this GET request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, all attributes (or all LDAP attributes that are mapped to SCIM claims) will be returned **ONLY IF** the GET request filters by the user's SCIM ID (the guid string). I was doing a GET request using a filter on externalId which is why it didn't return all attributes.